# How do I refer to a dbt source in Snowpark?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have defined a dbt source like so:

```yaml
version: 2

sources:
  - name: mysource
    database: MY_DATABASE
    schema: myschema
    tables:
      - name: table1
```

and am referencing it in a dbt model like so:

```sql
{%- set source_table = source('mysource', 'table1') -%}

SELECT * 
FROM {{ source_table }} source
```

(in reality its more complicated than this but for the purposes of demonstration, this will do.

I am now exploring Snowpark and I'd like to rewrite this model in Snowpark. The basic skeleton for a Snowpark model is:

```py
def model(dbt, session):
    # Must be either table or incremental (view is not currently supported)
    dbt.config(materialized = "table")

    # DataFrame representing an upstream model
    df = dbt.ref("my_first_dbt_model")
 
    return df
```

*([Create a simple python model](https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/data_engineering_with_snowpark_python_and_dbt/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2))*

In this example the source table is referred to using `dbt.ref()`. How do I refer to the source defined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, turns out its pretty easy:

```py
def model(dbt, session):
    # Must be either table or incremental (view is not currently supported)
    dbt.config(materialized = "table")

    # DataFrame representing an upstream model
    df = dbt.source('mysource', 'table1')
 
    return df
```